# Verificar si la posición ya está ocupada en un Tres en Raya

Tags: java

Sé que el código se puede mejorar y ahorrar muchas líneas, pero estoy empezando y todavía tengo que ir paso a paso. Mi problema es que cuando le toca por ejemplo al jugador 1 y pone una X en, supongamos, la posición 00, cuando le toca al jugador 2, si él pone la posición 00 se cambia la X por una O.

He intentado varias cosas con un if, pero no hay manera. También si meto una posición en "int x" e "int y" diferente a 0, 1 o 2 me sale error al ejecutar, el cual he intentado también arreglar con un if o incluso un try catch sin ningún éxito.

He mirado varios ejercicios sobre este juego, pero no me aclaro y prefiero seguir con mi código sin copiar otro código. Sé que el código que falta debe ir en el método `comprobarTresEnRaya`, para cuando se vaya a validar la posición.

```
public class TresEnRaya {

static private Boolean tresEnRaya=false; //determina si se ha producido la raya

static private int x = 0; // fila
static private int y = 0; //columna
static private char turno = '%'; //hay dos turnos X y O
private static Scanner e = new Scanner(System.in);
private static char[][] matriz = new char[3][3];


public static void main(String[] args) {
    TresEnRaya.imprimirTablero(matriz);

    for (int i = 1; i<=9 && tresEnRaya == false; i++){
         System.out.println();
         do{
         //Insertar fila y columna
              System.out.println("Introduce fila");
              x = e.nextInt();

              System.out.println("Introduce columna");
              y = e.nextInt();



         //Control de las cordenadas
              if(turno=='%'){
                  System.out.println("Le toca al jugador 1");
                  matriz[x][y]='X';
                  turno='-';
              }else{
                  System.out.println("Le toca al jugador 2");
                  matriz[x][y]='O';
                  turno='%';
              }

              //Validar posicion
              TresEnRaya.comprobarTresEnRaya(matriz, turno, x, y);


              //Imprimir tablero con las posiciones
              System.out.println();
              for (int z = 0; z < matriz.length; z++) {
                  System.out.println();
                  for (int j = 0; j < matriz[z].length; j++) {
                       System.out.print(matriz[z][j] + " ");
                  }
              }

         }while((x!=0 && x!=1 && x!=2) || (y!=0 && y!=1 && y!=2));



         System.out.println();
         //LLamada a los métodos
         TresEnRaya.comprobarColumna(matriz, turno, y);
         TresEnRaya.comprobarDiagonal(matriz, turno, x, y);
         TresEnRaya.comprobarFila(matriz, turno, x);

         //Imprimir al final del for    

         if(i == 9){
              System.out.println();
              System.out.println("EMPATE!");
              System.out.println("Fin del juego.");
         }
    }
}

//METODOS

private static void imprimirTablero(char[][] tablero){
     System.out.println("TABLERO");
         System.out.println();
         for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
              System.out.println();
              for (int j = 0; j < matriz.length; j++) {
              System.out.print((matriz[i][j] = '-') + " ");
              }
         }    
     System.out.println();
}

private static boolean comprobarTresEnRaya(char[][] tablero, char turno, int x,int y){

    return true;
}
private static boolean comprobarColumna(char[][] tablero, char turno, int y){

     if((matriz[0][0] == 'X') && (matriz[1][0] == 'X') && (matriz[2][0] == 'X')){
         System.out.println("Gana el jugador 1");
         tresEnRaya = true;
     }
     if((matriz[0][1] == 'X') && (matriz[1][1] == 'X') && (matriz[2][1] == 'X')){
         System.out.println("Gana el jugador 1");
         tresEnRaya = true;
     }

     if((matriz[0][2] == 'X') && (matriz[1][2] == 'X') && (matriz[2][2] == 'X')){
         System.out.println("Gana el jugador 1");
         tresEnRaya = true;
     }

     if((matriz[0][0] == 'O') && (matriz[1][0] == 'O') && (matriz[2][0] == 'O')){
         System.out.println("Gana el jugador 2");
         tresEnRaya = true;
     }
     if((matriz[0][1] == 'O') && (matriz[1][1] == '0') && (matriz[2][1] == 'O')){
         System.out.println("Gana el jugador 2");
         tresEnRaya = true;
     }

     if((matriz[0][2] == 'O') && (matriz[1][2] == 'O') && (matriz[2][2] == 'O')){
         System.out.println("Gana el jugador 2");
         tresEnRaya = true;
     }
     return true;
}
private static boolean comprobarDiagonal(char[][] tablero, char turno, int x, int y){
     if((matriz[0][0] == 'X') && (matriz[1][1] == 'X') && (matriz[2][2] == 'X')){
         System.out.println("Gana el jugador 1");
         tresEnRaya = true;
     }

     if((matriz[0][2] == 'X') && (matriz[1][1] == 'X') && (matriz[2][0] == 'X')){
         System.out.println("Gana el jugador 1");
         tresEnRaya = true;
     }

     if((matriz[0][0] == 'O') && (matriz[1][1] == 'O') && (matriz[2][2] == 'O')){
         System.out.println("Gana el jugador 2");
         tresEnRaya = true;
     }

     if((matriz[0][2] == 'O') && (matriz[1][1] == 'O') && (matriz[2][0] == 'O')){
         System.out.println("Gana el jugador 1");
         tresEnRaya = true;
     }
     return true;
}
private static boolean comprobarFila(char[][] tablero, char turno, int x){
     if((matriz[0][0] == 'X') && (matriz[0][1] == 'X') && (matriz[0][2] == 'X')){
         System.out.println("Gana el jugador 1");
         tresEnRaya = true;
     }
     if((matriz[1][0] == 'X') && (matriz[1][1] == 'X') && (matriz[1][2] == 'X')){
         System.out.println("Gana el jugador 1");
         tresEnRaya = true;
     }

     if((matriz[2][0] == 'X') && (matriz[2][1] == 'X') && (matriz[2][2] == 'X')){
         System.out.println("Gana el jugador 1");
         tresEnRaya = true;
     }

     if((matriz[0][0] == 'O') && (matriz[0][1] == 'O') && (matriz[0][2] == 'O')){
         System.out.println("Gana el jugador 2");
         tresEnRaya = true;
     }
     if((matriz[1][0] == 'O') && (matriz[1][1] == '0') && (matriz[1][2] == 'O')){
         System.out.println("Gana el jugador 2");
         tresEnRaya = true;
     }

     if((matriz[2][0] == 'O') && (matriz[2][1] == 'O') && (matriz[2][2] == 'O')){
         System.out.println("Gana el jugador 2");
         tresEnRaya = true;
     }

     return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la parte de `Control de cordenadas`al poner un condicional que verifique si la posicion tiene o no una O u una X me imprime que la posicion ya esta ocupada de esta forma

```
            if (turno == '%') {
                if(matriz[x][y] != 'O'){
                    System.out.println("Le toca al jugador 1");
                    matriz[x][y] = 'X';
                    turno = '-';
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Posición ya ocupada, no se permite sobre escribir la posicion");
                }
            } else {
                if(matriz[x][y] != 'X'){
                    System.out.println("Le toca al jugador 2");
                    matriz[x][y] = 'O';
                    turno = '%';
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Posición ya ocupada, no se permite sobre escribir la posicion");
                }
            }
```

luego de esto solo tuvieras que ver como volver a repetir el turno del que puso la columna y fila repetida sin que i aumente en 1

Comment: Gracias, lo de volver a repetir turno es fácil i-- para que no siga avanzando si la posición está ocupada. Ahora sólo me queda por averiguar cómo al meter una coordenada diferente a 0 1 2 no me salte error.

Comment: De igual forma lo puedes hacer con un if, si mete entre 0 y 2 que siga sino que le diga que posición no valida y que repita el turno, por cierto te felicito por el ejercicio, es algo que desarrolla muy bien la lógica :)